# Is if(null != object) better than if(object!=null)

Tags: c#

I have seen null checks done both ways:

```
if(object!=null)
```

and

```
if(null!=object)
```

Is one really better than the other or is it just preference?  My preference is the first.

Comment: No difference. 1!=2, 2!=1, in English, one doesn't equal two, and two doesn't equal one.

Comment: For readability's sake, I'd prefer the first one as well. Since the `object` is dynamic.

Comment: better if you put variable to compare first ..

Comment: I'm not a C# programmer but have done a lot of C and C++. The reason for doing `if ( null != object )` in C/C++ (assuming `null` is a constant) is to avoid the pitfall of erroneously typing `if ( object = null )` and unintentionally doing an assignment. Of course, with appropriate warnings on one would hopefully catch it. If the constant comes first, the compiler will generate an error.

Comment: I find option 1 MUCH more readable. The only barely viable argument I've heard for the second option is that it gives a compiler error if you forget to write == and use = instead (which honestly shouldn't happen if you coded for more than a few days).

Comment: Oh, very smart. @mbratch If you place a constant first, there's no way you could assign it. Where as if you placed the variable first, you get the awkward position of debugging something very simple.

Comment: In c#, all the arguments for the first one vanish and you're left with the second option, which is better English.  (You don't say "is red the color of this block?"  You say, "is this block red?")

Comment: `childishly ridicule` What! No! I'm actually considering programming my future projects like this.

Comment: I think that @mbratch got it correct as to why I see this in code sometimes - it's a holdover from C/C++.  In C#, the compiler will complain if you say if(object=null) so it's no longer necessary and I agree with the better English.

Comment: @mbratch In C#, `if (object = null)` won't compile, because `object` is not convertible to `bool`.

Comment: @KirkWoll, that is true. But C# isn't English. haha ;)

Comment: @svick, indeed. My caveat was that I haven't done any `C#` so I wasn't sure if it would hold in that world. It's a C/C++ notion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is the comparison, in one you are comparing object with null and the other you are comparing null with object. In the former it shows that the object that is the more important factor, and in the latter the null is more important. The compiler does not mind but it is common sense and English/programming convention.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't make any difference to the compiler, for white != and == the order doesn't matter. However, Most others and I will say that it makes a lot more sense to do object != null. This is read as "if the object isn't null", which makes sense, and null != object is read as "if null doesn't equal object" which doesn't make as much sense.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it makes any technical difference.

Regarding readability, I would argue that the former ("If myObject is not equal to null") reads better than the latter ("If null is not equal to myObject"). I would argue that the former is a better fit to the subject–verb–object (SVO) kind of sentence structure (where myObject is the subject of the sentence and null is the object of the sentence) typically found in English.

I'm assuming that the main readers of your code are native English speakers. Perhaps the latter would be a more logical structure for some languages where the sentence structure differs.